# How to stop an element in XML from being empty using XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I want empty elements to not be accepted while XML validation using my XSD

My XML:

```
<Request>
<Query>Select * from Table</Query>
<Query></Query>
</Request>
```

My XSD:

```
<xs:simpleType name="className">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="1" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="status">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
        <xs:minInclusive value="100" />
        <xs:maxExclusive value="600" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="requires">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="1" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:complexType name="sql">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
            <xs:attribute name="requires" type="requires"/>
            <xs:attribute name="when" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="limit" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="offset" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="classname" type="className" />
            <xs:attribute name="status" type="status"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="query">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="sql">
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="Request">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Query" type="query" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I want the query tag to be not accepted if it is empty, so this  and  should be invalid. Hope my question is to the point. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restricting empty elements in xsd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399952/restricting-empty-elements-in-xsd)

Comment: I already have a `simpleType`. As the answer suggests by @Michael Kay I just made it generic and then reused it everywhere that required a similar restriction. So technically my code already had the answer. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already got a simpleType `className` that defines a non-empty string. Rename it to `non-empty-string` to reflect the intent, then change the sql type do define it as an extension of `non-empty-string` rather than of `xs:string`.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was pretty dumb of me. I declared a new simpleType just for non-empty strings as I may need to put some regex for the className in future.

Answer (score 0):

use the attribute `minOccurs=1`  on the element in the schema if you want it to be mandatory

Comment: That's just to specify how many Query tags I want minimum in my XML, I can give minOccurs=0. But that's not my point.